# Laravel AbstractVariables.php line 54 Expected name to be a string

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, composer-php

I am using Laravel 6 with visual studio code. The last successfully command i run is given below with their out put.

```
php artisan config:clear
Configuration cache cleared!
```

But after that, whatever command i do execute it gives me an error

```
In AbstractVariables.php line 54:
Expected name to be a string.
```

I have tried to execute given below commands, but all of these ends up with above mentioned error.

```
composer update
php artisan serve
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

I have tried to find out file named "AbstractVariables.php" and i did find it in given below directory

```
vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Environment
```

I have tried to read what is code is given on line 54 of file named "AbstractVariables.php"

```
public function get($name){
    if (!is_string($name)) {
       throw new InvalidArgumentException('Expected name to be a string.');
    }    
    return $this->getInternal($name);
}
```

And the comments above this function is...

```
* Get an environment variable.    
* @param string $name    
* @throws \InvalidArgumentException
* @return string|null
```

So, it means it is searching environment variable some where and it is not able to find string there.

`.env` file in my profile has all variables name. 
Now, I am not able to understand what else is missing, I have done a lot of search on google but didn't find any thing in this regard.

Comment: Adding a `dump($name);` in that function would give you more info. And maybe us also, so feel free to edit the result of it in your question.  Don't forget to remove it afterward of course. Or just wipe out the full `vendor` folder before running a `composer install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred when I configured [spatie/laravel-analytics](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics) to fetch google analytics data to display in admin panel of website.
In order to make it functional it was required to add `'view_id' => env('ANALYTICS_VIEW_ID')` in `config/analytics.php` file.

**What mistake was done?**

In `config/analytics.php` file I added view id without single quote mark which was wrong. Example is given below....

```
'view_id' => 123456789,
```

After that whenever I hit follow commands i get error

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Error is given below...

```
In AbstractVariables.php line 54:
Expected name to be a string.
```

**How I solved issue?**

I have updated `config/analytics.php` as per documentation and changed it like given below...

```
'view_id' => env('ANALYTICS_VIEW_ID')
```

And in `.env` file added environment variable `ANALYTICS_VIEW_ID`

```
ANALYTICS_VIEW_ID=216007652
```

After that both commands `php artisan config:clear`and `php artisan cache:clear` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're an idiot like me and accidentally entered/clear an entry in a config file like so,

`'url' => env('')`

you might get this error. Since I have dozens of config files, I ripped them all out except app.php and then ran php artisan, adding files until it was back to normal, then continued to add them back until it failed again.

Or... now that I know, I'd just search the project for a blank env('')

Answer (score 0):

check your `config/app.php` and try to check your .`env`, if something is missing then that would cause error. Example `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)` and `'debug' => env(true)`.